# how to use method lasso in cox model using glmnet?

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

I have the survival data includes 252 patients, 25 independent variables and 35 events. I want to use lasso method in cox model to these data. I use `glmnet` for it. but, I encountered an error which I cannot explain or solve. I tried several times. Each times I get Error in coxnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :   negative event times encountered;  not permitted for Cox family.
can anyone help me solve this problem ?

r codes:

```
library(foreign)
dataset=read.spss("E:/dializ/data/total11.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE)
attach(dataset)
head(dataset)
library(glmnet)
library(survival)
x <- model.matrix( ~ group + sen + sex + B.G +  bmi + literacy + maritaly + job + smoking + db1 + db2 + db3 + db4 + db5 + a.d  + w + y.dialyz + h.f +
HCV + HBV + HIV + anemi + eprex - 1, dataset)
y <- Surv(time, status)
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family="cox", alpha=1)
fit=glmnet(x,y,family="cox", alpha=1)
plot(cv.fit)
cv.fit$lambda.min
Coefficients <- coef(fit, s = cv.fit$lambda.min)
Active.Index <- which(Coefficients != 0)
Active.Coefficients <- Coefficients[Active.Index]
```

r output:

```
Error in coxnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
negative event times encountered;  not permitted for Cox family
```

Comment: Could you please show the result of `summary(time)`?

Comment: @EdM -  > summary(time)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    5.00   10.00   10.92   15.00   52.00

Comment: Try removing cases with 0 values of `time`; `glmnet` doesn't deal with those well. Those cases aren't providing useful information in any event.

Comment: i have replaced zero values of time with one. and again, i have run above codes. fortunately, no error found. thanks alot

Comment: The same error occured when I analyze the survivla data of Pancreatic cancer form ICGC for determine its relationship betweem certain gene expression level and survival time. The cv.glmnet command can make its function after deleting those patient samples with survival time equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Try coding x and y in below order and this might work

y <- Surv(time, status)

x <- model.matrix(y ~ group + sen + sex + B.G +  bmi + literacy + maritaly + job + smoking + db1 + db2 + db3 + db4 + db5 + a.d  + w + y.dialyz + h.f +
HCV + HBV + HIV + anemi + eprex - 1, dataset)

Comment: ???? this doesn't make sense to me.  Can you explain the logic behind your answer?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.  It appears correct to me.